# Titanium Alloy Filter Function - How do I access the view that I'm iterating over

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I have a view in Titanium Alloy which loops through a list of videos in a collection, like so:

```
<View dataCollection="videos" dataFilter="recentlyAddedFilter">
    <ImageView image="{img}" width="200">
          <Label text="{title}"></Label>  
    </ImageView>
</View>
```

And I have a filter function called `recentlyAddedFilter`, defined in my controller like so:

```
function recentlyAddedFilter(collection) {
    return collection.where({title:'A title'});
}
```

I'm going to create multiple versions of this `view` component, so I would like the filter function to be able to access each individual component that it is applied to, just like I can use the `collection` inside the filter function. So it would be great if I could do something like this:

```
function recentlyAddedFilter(collection) {
    theComponent.width = "200dp"; // change property on component that calls this function
    return collection.where({title:'A title'});
}
```

Is there a way that I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead use the [`dataTransform`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Data_Binding) function to add an attribute to the JSON used to construct the view, and then with the added custom attribute, call it much like any other attribute. For example:

```
<View dataCollection="videos" dataFilter="recentlyAddedFilter" 
                              dataTransform="recentlyAddedTransform">
    <!-- Pass the customWidth attribute that was added in the transform function -->
    <ImageView image="{img}" width="{customWidth}">
          <Label text="{title}"></Label>  
    </ImageView>
</View>
```

So your controller would look like this:

```
// Takes a collection
function recentlyAddedFilter(collection) {
    return collection.where({title:'A title'});
}

// Takes a model
function recentlyAddedTransform(model) {
    // Make sure to convert the model to JSON
    var transform = model.toJSON();
    // Add a custom width attribute to the model
    transform.customWidth = "200dp"; 
    return transform;
}
```

Remember that in the `dataTransform` function you are working with an individual model, but you are returning JSON.